# Switch from Files to DB sessions on old magento version

Tags: magento

I have a client running an old version of magento.  It appears that there is no session_save in the local.xml, like in newer versions of magento.  Any idea where to change this setting in the older version of magento: The version is 1.1.4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own session handler for that Magento version. This feature appeared in 1.3 I guess, because of customer's load balancers...

Comment: not the answer I was hoping for.. but the answer none the less :)

Comment: @Chris, anyway you can try to move session management from a newer Magento version.